# How to get last row a value without using loops for MySql query in limited more than 1

Tags: php, mysql

I want to known how to get last row a value without using while loop for mysql query.

Select data:

```
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM status 
 WHERE author = '$pname'
   AND postdate >= '$lsposttime' 
 ORDER 
    BY postdate ASC 
 LIMIT 4";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

I want to get 4th row postdate value withoutusing loops.

Not using this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from status
where author = '$pname'
    and postdate >= '$lsposttime'
order by postdate asc LIMIT 3, 1
```

this will get the fourth row

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM STATUS 
    WHERE author='$pname' 
    AND postdate >= '$lsposttime' 
    ORDER BY postdate ASC LIMIT 4
) tnp 
ORDER BY postdate DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This will return the **last** row. So if the result only return 2 row it will give the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use offset in mysql for fetch data from exact place an order.

For your Requirement your query will looks like:

`$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM status 
 WHERE author = '$pname'
   AND postdate >= '$lsposttime' 
 ORDER 
    BY postdate ASC 
 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);`

And for more use of offset you can discover from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)